# My libprotobuf.a work for Mac Os but not for iOS Device

Tags: c++, ios, macos

I am working with Cocos2dx and trying to use protobuf for communication with the server by JAVA.

I have just downloaded google protocol buffer v3.3.0 and follow the installation document. After installing it, I got a static library **libprotobuf.a** file, I used it for running on a Mac-Desktop, it works perfectly, but when I change to build on a iOS device, it's not working.

[Errors when building for iOS device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5k4O.jpg)

I have spent many hours to find a solution and or **dynamic library C++ of protobuf 3.3.0**, however, I have nothing at all.

I really need someone's help. Could you give me some solutions, please!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Please post errors as verbatim text not as an image.